# Use new email for google account

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-account, email, authentication

I have a google account based on an email name that I don't really like(used native spelling instead of the English one and now live abroad). I have LOTS of things tied to it though, (Android, drive etc) plus apps that login with Google authentication.

I exclude 3rd party apps that used directly the email for making an account, since not much can be done for that.

I would like to start using a new email with a better name for everything, or have both accounts kind of managed in parallel, without need to think which of the two I am really using.

It must be such a common need, but can't find anything conclusive online... Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new account.

The following Google support page is about a different topic (merging accounts), but contains info and a link about transferring data from one account to another, which is possible on a per-product basis:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304

Regarding the Gmail email address, you can let the old one forward emails to the new one. Additionally, in the new one, under Gmail Settings --> Accounts and Import, you can set from which address you reply by default, and what the `Reply-To` address should be.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail allows to [send emails from a different email address of alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

> If you own another email address, you can send mail as that address.
>   For example:
>
> - Yahoo, Outlook, or other non-Gmail address
> - Your work, school, or business domain or alias, like @yourschool.edu or youralias@gmail.com
> - Another Gmail address

Also Gmail is able to [Check emails from other accounts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en)

> If you have multiple email accounts, you can check them in Gmail. You
>   can choose from the following options:
>
> - **Get all messages (old and new)**: Choose this option if you still use another email address, including another Gmail address. There
>     might be a short delay in showing new messages.
> - **Get only old messages**: Choose this option if you recently switched to Gmail from another provider.
> - **Forward only new messages**: Choose this if you want your new messages immediately.